# Postgres: Best way to determine changes in table without scanning entire table

Tags: postgresql, etl

I am designing a etl to take incremental changes from postgres table.

How to detect whether table rows modified after last etl run without doing full table scan ?

Comment: Answer by Vao Tsun is correct for your question, but possibly more optimal way to replicate data from PostgreSQL is to use triggers and those don't need to check `pg_stat_all_tables`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd save stats and compare from `pg_stat_all_tables` for that, eg I just ran sequentially:

```
t=# select schemaname,relname,n_tup_ins,n_tup_upd,n_tup_del from pg_stat_all_tables where relname = 'rapid_inserts';
 schemaname |      relname       | n_tup_ins | n_tup_upd | n_tup_del
------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------
 public     | rapid_inserts| 254681563 |         0 |         0
(1 row)

Time: 10.921 ms
t=# select schemaname,relname,n_tup_ins,n_tup_upd,n_tup_del from pg_stat_all_tables where relname = 'rapid_inserts';
 schemaname |      relname       | n_tup_ins | n_tup_upd | n_tup_del
------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------
 public     | rapid_inserts| 254681569 |         0 |         0
(1 row)

Time: 10.980 ms
```

It means 6 rows were inserted in barely second. same would work for updates and deletes...

Comment: Thanks Vao for your quick response.  Is there a way to find which row got inserted/updated/deletd, so that etl can process only those rows directly ?